# NSArray, Plist, NSDictionary or recommendation on storing data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have tried a lot of different things but not sure what to do.  I have a mysql database table that I'm trying to convert into something usable for my iphone app.  I need to store about 90 rows of data.  Each row has 3 columns (2 NSStrings and an integer).  I was thinking the best thing to store this in is an NSDictionary but I also have to load this into a pickerview and using an NSDictionary seems a lot more complicated than using an array.  Also, performance-wise, my understanding is that if I use a plist, it will load all keys/values into memory whereas sqlite will not.  Any recommendations?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a class the represents a row. This class will have 3 properties (2 `NSString`s and one `int`). So you will have an array that contains 90 instances of this class.

Alternatively, you can use an array that contains 90 dictionaries (each dictionary represents a row). But I recommend the first method.

Finally, 90 values are not a lot of data and you can use either a plist or SQLite. But I think SQLite will be an overkill for your app and that it will add more complexity without any sensible advantages.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the perfect situation for creating a class that represents the row.  I did this and then loaded the data via the plist.  Everything works.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't anything more or less complicated about `NSDictionary` vs. `NSArray`.

For only 90 rows of data, I wouldn't worry about the memory.  A plist sounds like a sensible solution, reading the plist data into an `NSArray` containing instances of an `NSObject` subclass that appropriately encapsulates your row data.